# how to omit XSD schema tag 'sequence' with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

1. I have applied some XSLT formatter for our XML files (XML feeds), kind of prettifying , tags are in **alphabetical order**:

```
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*/*/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="name()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2.But few of ours XML files originally using specific XSD-schema which applying tag `<xs:sequence>` which demands **strict sequence** of the specified elements and schema validator fails.

Of course we are able to exclude this few files from prettifying, but question is : can we configure our XSLT in some way to avoid excluding these files?
XSD-schema cannot be changed.

Comment: So, you're imposing an alphabetical order by name that violates the sequence specified in the XSD?  If that's correct, it would appear that you have to decide what's more important to you: Changing the order to be alphabetical or preserving validation according to the (unchangeable) XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to have five identical template rules with different match patterns. A single template rule with `match="*"` will do the job just fine.

Secondly, order of elements is often significant whether or not there is a schema. Sometimes there is semantic significance (the order of paragraphs in a chapter needs to be retained, as does the order of authors of an article), sometimes there is a conventional order other than alphabetical (a table heading precedes the table body); sometimes receiving applications are written to expect a particular order. So I would suggest only applying your transformation to those rare documents where order of elements doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course try to use predicates like `/*/*/*/*[not(self::xs:sequence)]` in your match patterns, declaring `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`. I won't try to spell out which patterns need that but I don't think an XSD schema can have an `xs:sequence` as `/*` or `/*/*`.